# Jasmine Custom Boot Within AngularJS - Executing Tests On Button Click

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

We want to test API's using jasmine. We want to run the tests from within our application by creating a debug tab with a button to kick off the tests.

If I use the standard boot.js from jasmine, the tests get kicked off succesfully, but we don't control when they run.

If I do my own custom boot js file I get an error that says describe not defined.

What is the best way to kick off our own tests on a button click?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

       <script data-require="jasmine@2.0.0rc2" data-semver="2.0.0rc2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <link data-require="jasmine@2.0.0rc2" data-semver="2.0.0rc2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine.css" />
    <script data-require="jasmine@2.0.0rc2" data-semver="2.0.0rc2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jasmine@2.0.0rc2" data-semver="2.0.0rc2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>


    <script src="app.js"></script>

 <script src="test.spec.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello  {{name}}!</p>

    <button ng-click='runTest()'> Run Tests </button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the issue by writing our own custom boot js file for Jasmin.  We removed the window.onLoad event which kicked off the jasmin.execute() tests.

In the controller we used RequireJs to dynamically load the spec tests and then run them.

See this article for more information.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/webdev/uidevelopment/javascript/unit-testing-with-jasmine-2-0-and-require-js/